# How to create bucket on oracle cloud with public read permissions

Tags: php, amazon-s3, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to create a bucket with public read permissions on oracle cloud services via PHP.
I am able to create the bucket using AWS compatibility method:

```
require dirname( __DIR__ ).'/composer/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client(array(
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'access key',
        'secret' => 'secret key',
    ],
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-ashburn-1',
    'bucket_endpoint' => true,
    'endpoint' => 'https://namespace.compat.objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/test-bucket',
));
$s3->getEndpoint();
$s3->putObject([ 'Bucket' => 'test-bucket', 'Key' => 'test-bucket' ]);
```

But this creates a private bucket.

I have tried to send the permissions in body:

```
$mRes = $s3->putObject([ 'Bucket' => $pa_sName, 'Key' => $pa_sName, 'Body' => json_encode( [ 'publicAccessType' => 'ObjectRead' ] ) ]);
```

But it ends up with MalformedXML error, probably because this request does not expect any body payload.

The AWS Compatibility contains only PUT Bucket:
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/s3objectstorage/20160918/Bucket/PutBucket
which does not allow/specify the access type parameter.

The POST method Create Bucket does specify it:
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Bucket/CreateBucket
here https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/datatypes/CreateBucketDetails

But I did not find a way how to do the POST request via AWS Compatibility.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You can't do it using the AWS Compatibility layer.  Oracle doesn't support the [ACL layer, either on the objects or buckets](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/s3compatibleapi.htm).  You'll need to [set the bucket to be public](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/managingbuckets.htm), outside of the AWS layer.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to give it a try with the native OCI Beta PHP SDK for this use case? Please drop a note at oci_sdk_team_ww_grp@oracle.com and I am happy to share the beta version with instructions.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to do it via the REST API with the help of the signer library: https://github.com/hitrov/oci-api-php-request-sign